# Retrieve List of Files using Python in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, events, event-handling, watchdog

I am stuck with a problem.
I am using watchdog in Python for Mac OS X to monitor directory events.

Whenever there is any addition to the watched directory, watchdog's `on_created()` function is overridden, and whenever there is any deletion in the watched directory, watchdog's `on_deleted()` function is overridden.

Now, what I am looking for is, to maintain an array or a list of those files which have been added or deleted. There should be 2 arrays, one for maintaing the files which have been added, and one for maintaing the files which have been deleted.

Here is my code:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler) :
    def on_created(self, event):
        print "Created"
        logging.info(event)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print "Deleted"
        logging.info(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Have you looked at [FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) and the Python package [MacFSEvents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents)?

Comment: Hey drewk, yes...have gone through it already...but of no use in this case, unfortunately....have come across a wrapper called watchdog, which monitors this and stores in an event...how shall we retrieve the list of files from this event object?

Comment: Not clear what are you really asking for here. `event.src_path` is the path for the deleted/created file. Do what you want with it...

Comment: Hey Takoi, thanks for reverting. That problem was quite old and have already found a solution for the same.